# Why isn't the sort method working?

Tags: java

I have to sort an array of fractions here is my code for the class which is working fine.

```
public class Fraction implements Comparable<Fraction>{
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction(int num, int den){
        numerator = num;
        denominator = den;
    }

    public int compareTo(Fraction fraction){
        if(decimalValue()>fraction.decimalValue()){
            return 1;
        }else if(decimalValue()<fraction.decimalValue()){
            return -1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public Fraction reduce(int numerator, int denominator){

  if(numerator==0&&denominator==0){
     numerator = 0;
     denominator = 0;
  }
  else{
     for(int x = Math.min(Math.abs(numerator), Math.abs(denominator)); x>0; x--){
        if(denominator == numerator){
           numerator = 1;
           denominator = 1;
        }
        else if(numerator == 0){
           numerator = 0;
           denominator = 1;
        }
        else if(numerator%x==0 && denominator%x==0){
           numerator = numerator/x;
           denominator = denominator/x; 
        }
     }
  }

    public double decimalValue(){
        double decimal = (numerator*1.0)/(1.0*denominator);
        return decimal;
    } 
    public String toString(){
        reduce(numerator, denominator);
        return ((numerator) + "/" + (denominator));
    }
}
```

For some reason the sort() is not working if I used it with a comparator like in the answer it works but I don't understand why this doesn't work. Here is the tester:

```
public class FractionChecker{
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int n, d;
        Random rand = new Random();
        Fraction[] f = new Fraction [20];
        for (int j= 0; j<20; j++){
            n = rand.nextInt(20);
            d = rand.nextInt(19)+1;           
            f[j] = new Fraction (n,d);
        }

        System.out.println("Unsorted " + Arrays.toString(f));
        Arrays.sort(f);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
      ----jGRASP exec: java FractionChecker
      Unsorted [7/6, 15/14, 5/15, 8/9, 19/16, 16/5, 11/16, 2/9, 11/10, 10/12,       12/11, 9/18, 15/4, 11/4, 10/7, 12/8, 13/14, 19/5, 19/15, 13/5]
       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Fraction cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
      at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1144)
      at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1155)
      at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1155)
      at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1079)
      at FractionChecker.main(FractionChecker.java:18)

     ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
     ----jGRASP: operation complete.

This is the error I am getting when I use Arrays.sort(f) and I am not sure why.
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `Arrays.sort` instead of `Collections.sort` -- Collections is for Lists and other collections. `f` is an array.

Comment: `f` is an array, so you need to use `Arrays.sort()`. Also `sort()` doesn't have a return value, so you can't print it.

Comment: I changed it to sort but now it is saying java.lang.ClassCastException: Fraction cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Comment: @Sarah you first class doesn't compile, is it the complete code?

Comment: No there is more I think the only thing I forgot was the decimalValue I will add that I think it will compile then

Comment: Well you haven't defined `reduce()`, but removing that call and closing off the class I get the above code to compile and work without the exception...

Comment: Well, I had to add a `return this; }` to `reduce()`, but it still compiles and works without the cast error. I suspect the problem may lie with jGrasp and generics, because at one point things were `Comparable` and then they got generics `Comparable<T>`. I can't say I know much about or use jGrasp though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collections.sort` expects a `List` whose type implements Comparable. You're providing an array of Fraction objects instead.

You should use `Arrays.sort` instead:

```
Arrays.sort(f);
```

If the above throws a `ClassCastException` for some reason, you can try this version of `Arrays.sort`, which requires a `Comparator` as an argument that will do the comparing:

```
Arrays.sort(f, new java.util.Comparator<Fraction>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Fraction f1, Fraction f2) {
        return f1.compareTo(f2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your `decimalValue` code. A better way to compare fractions in any case may be:

```
long left = numerator * other.denominator;
long right = other.numerator * denominator;

if (left == right) {
  return 0;
} else if (left < right) {
  return -1;
} else /* if (left > right) */ {
  return 1;
}
```

Not that this will increase your performance drastically but it is just neater and handles division by zero in a sensible way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot comment on other posts but this is wrong. `Arrays.sort()` does not need a comparator, it can use natural order if only one argument is passed.

Comment: I changed this now it is saying java.lang.ClassCastException: Fraction cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable. Do you know why this is

Comment: That worked but is there a way to do it without the comparator

Comment: @Sarah I am unable to reproduce the exception using the code you provided. Can you include the stack trace in your question?

Comment: It worked when I used the code above, but I don't really know what that code above is so I would rather not do it that way and I think I am supposed to use natural order

Comment: @Sarah Try recompiling your `Fraction` class and then running `FractionChecker` with `Arrays.sort(f)`. If that doesn't work, then try recompiling using `implements java.lang.Comparable<Fraction>`.

Comment: @Sarah `java.util.Comparator` is just another way to sort the elements by comparing them. Under the hood, `Arrays.sort` uses natural ordering by using the `compareTo` method in the manner used above.

Comment: @Sarah when some library needs to compare your objects and so call the `compareTo` method, it cannot just invoke the method as it does not know what the type of the object is. It therefore has to cast to Comparable interface which implements this method but you must declare this. I see that in your example you do but check if you actually have in your code. What I said isn't strictly accurate but makes it slightly easier to explain

Answer (score 0):

The code below works and prints `success`

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Fraction implements Comparable<Fraction>{
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction(int num, int den){
        numerator = num;
        denominator = den;
    }

    public int compareTo(Fraction fraction){
        if(decimalValue()>fraction.decimalValue()){
            return 1;
        }else if(decimalValue()<fraction.decimalValue()){
            return -1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public double decimalValue(){
        double decimal = (numerator*1.0)/(1.0*denominator);
        return decimal;
    } 
    public String toString(){
        return ((numerator) + "/" + (denominator));
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Fraction[] fractions = new Fraction[2];
        fractions[0] = new Fraction(1,1);
        fractions[1] = new Fraction(2,3);
        Arrays.sort(fractions);
        System.out.println("success");
    }
}
```